# Incorrect Normal Calculations on a chair mesh when exported to substance

Tags: normals

I have a chair that I will use inside a composition but when exported to substance it displays the normals incorrectly, let me explain.

In this image we can see the chair on the left has correct normals, hence the blue color, the chair on the right has wrong normals, hence the red color, theorically.

[image]

Yet when imported into substance the chair with the "correct" normals has them all messed up, while the incorrect chair has some weird shadows but is displayed better.

[image]

I have already tried with

- recalculate outside
- taking on and off auto smooth on object data properties
- On edit > Normals > reset vectors

Does anyone know why this is happening and can help me?

I need the chair to be displayed with correct normals, not the weird shadow nor missing faces.

Comment: In Blender, Object mode, Right side Properties panel >Item tab > Transform > Scale...... can you check to see if the chair that is importing into SP with the inverted normals has any negative Scale values. For example:  X  -1.00 or Y -1.00  or  Z -1.00 (or all 3) If so then with the chair selected you wil need to apply the scale so that the values are positive values by selecting the chair and opening the Apply menu with CTRL + A and choose the Scale option. Then check the normals again and if necessary use the Recalculate Outside tool.

Comment: Omgg yes! That was it I cannot thank you enough, you are a lifesaver